# Transition a DIV element while reverting transition on a another element - Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have php generating several DIV tags populated with information for a database. 
A DIV height of 400px will display all information. However, I render the DIVs to height=50PX on the page with CSS.

example:

```
<div style="height: 50px">Info</div>
<div style="height: 50px">Info</div>
<div style="height: 50px">Info</div>
<div style="height: 50px">Info</div>
```

etc

I need some help with javascript method and functions, that will run when I click on the DIV element, the function should change the style.property.height to 400px and simultaneously reduce any other div that was expanded to 400px back to 50px. When the DIV is action i.e. it's at 400px, it should NOT change no matter how many time it's clicked on, but once click out of the DIV or another div it should revert to 50px

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: I've tried a few methods, but nothing usable, either only one DIV expands, or all expands, nothing reverts back to 50xp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give all the `div`s the same class to select them by (with `document.querySelectorAll`) to change their styles. You can loop through all of the `div`s with `Array.prototype.forEach` to change their heights back to `50px`. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5dLpjkg/embedded/result

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");
var input = document.getElementById("num");
document.getElementById("transitionBtn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var num = input.value;
  var div = divs[num-1];
  [].slice.call(divs).forEach(function(el){
    if(el.style.height!=="50px"&&el!==div){
      el.style.height = "50px";
    }
  });
  div.style.height="200px";
});
```

```css
.myClass{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: height 2s;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 50px" class="myClass">Info #1</div>
<div style="height: 50px" class="myClass">Info #2</div>
<div style="height: 50px" class="myClass">Info #3</div>
<div style="height: 50px" class="myClass">Info #4</div>
<input type="number" id="num" placeholder="Div number" min="1" max="4" style="width: 30%" value="1">
<p/>
<button id="transitionBtn">Run Transition</button>
```